# Moodle Authentication (auth_googleoauth2) plugin not working

Tags: plugins, oauth, oauth-2.0, moodle, google-signin

i am using moodle 3.0.
I want to login with on my website, so i have downloaded Authentication (auth_googleoauth2) plugin from moodle directories. 
also put the clientID and client secret into setting plugine page. 
But on login page still not showing buttons for "login with google".
Any thing i am missing can any one help how to use this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Is it enabled? Go to site admin -> plugins -> authentication -> manage authentication

https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Managing_authentication#Setting_the_authentication_method.28s.29

Comment: Yes, Web services authentication is enabled.

Comment: web services is different to authentication, authentication is when you log in via the front end. web services is for external applications.

Comment: Ok then which option i have to enable ??